# Is there a method similar to isUpdated which notifies me if the relationships of a NSManagedObject has been updated?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

isUpdated method in NSManagedObject informs me if the entity has been updated.

However it doesn't inform me if an entity which is in a relationship with the entity has been updated.

Should I go through all relationships by myself ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of approaches to consider would be...
Observe the context to see if any object has changed, the use some keypath operators to drill into specifics... That approach could be error prone and cumbersome...

The better approach would be to make a special notification and send the appropriate info in that notification... Then the observer only has to observe that notification, rather than kvo all of the keys.

maybe something like:

```
static NSString * kClassADidChangeKey = @"kClassADidChangeKey";
static NSString * kClassAKeyKey = @"kClassAKeyKey";
@interface ClassA : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString * keyOfInterest;

@end

@implementation ClassA

@dynamic keyOfInterest;

-(void)setKeyOfInterest:(NSString*)theValue
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"keyOfInterest"];

    NSMutableDictionary * userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [userInfo setValue:key forKey:kClassAKeyKey];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kClassADidChangeKey object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:theValue forKey:@"keyOfInterest"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"keyOfInterest"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more the notification approach ? Should I add an Observer for the interested entities ?

Comment: It depends on your conditions, you could just check all of them to see if you are interested... There is trade off between programming time and performance... Like everything.

Comment: But I mean, what should the special notification be ?

Comment: i just changed it a little bit as it doesn't seem that the didChangeValueForKey: gets called if you don't set up the observers first.

Comment: Since I've just 3 relationships who needs to be monitored, I've just explicitly written down which key paths to check. But I will keep in mind your solution for more complex models. Thanks